# Flatten a list which one of its properties is another list of object

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class Owner
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Main
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert `List<Main>` to `List<FlatList>` where FlatList is

```
public class FlatList
{
        public string Id { get; set; }          // Id from Main
        public string Name { get; set; }        // Name from Main
        public string OwnerId { get; set; }     // Id from each Owner in a Main's Owner
        public string OwnerName { get; set; }   // Name from each Owner in a Main's Owner
}
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out the LinQ query to perform this operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to flatten a sequence of Main objects:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So it projects each Main object into sequence of `FlatList` objects and then flattens resulting sequences into one `FlatList` sequence

```
var flatList = mainList.SelectMany(m => 
    m.Owners.Select(o => 
        new FlatList { 
              Id = m.Id, 
              Name = m.Name, 
              OwnerId = o.Id,
              OwnerName = o.Name
         })).ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Main> mainList = ...
var flatList = (
    from main in mainList
    from owner in main.Owners
    select new FlatList {
        Id = main.Id, Name = main.Name,
        OwnerId = owner.Id, OwnerName = owner.Name
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using linq (secret looping behind the scenes):

```
from m in mainList
from o in m.Owners
select new FlatList
{
   Id  = m.Id,
   Name = m.Name,
   OwnerId = o.OwnerId ,
   OwnerName = o.OwnerName 
};
```